In PostgreSQL, how can I select all the contents in two tables without explicitly listing all the fields?
Since there are many fields in both tables A and B, when joining the two tables for query, if all the fields are explicitly listed, the workload will be huge and the code will be very long. How can I select all the columns without explicitly listing all the fields?
For example, I have two tables A and B, and they have a common field id. Normally, if I want to select all the fields in both tables A and B, the SQL code is written like this: select a., b.x1, b.x2, b.x3...... from a left join b using (id). If there are hundreds of fields in both tables A and B, the code will be very long. How can I select all the fields in both tables A and B by using a query similar to select a., b.* from a left join b using (id) and merge the same fields?

"...and merge the same fields"  That will not be possible.  (whatever you do mean by "merge the same fields").

please provide a full [mre]

If you want to select all columns from both tables, simply write a.*,b.*. If this is not what you want, you didn't explain correctly what you want.

The JOIN...USING() syntax merges the columns named for the join.
Other than that, there is no wildcard syntax in SQL that merges the same columns. SQL does not assume columns are the same if they have the same name.
For example, you could have a column created_at in both tables, yet they have different values. Just because they have the same name doesn't mean they have the same content.
You'll just have to list the columns you want.
It seems like the real problem is the tables have hundreds of columns. That's a code smell — usually it indicates bad design.
